# How printf function handle %f specification?

Tags: c, floating-point, string-formatting

I have a couple of programs whose output I cannot understand:

#### Program 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i=1;
  float k=2;
  printf("k is %f \n",k);
  printf("i is %f \n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Output is at http://codepad.org/ZoYsP6dc

```
k is 2.000000 
i is 2.000000
```

#### Program 2

Now one more example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char i='a';
  int a=5;
  printf("i is %d \n",i);  // here %d type cast char value in int
  printf("a is %f \n",a);  // hete %f dont typecast float value
  printf("a is %f \n",(float)a);  // if we write (float) with %f then it works
  return 0;
}
```

Here output is at http://codepad.org/XkZVRg64

```
i is 97 
a is 2.168831 
a is 5.000000
```

#### Question

What is going on here?  Why am I getting the outputs shown?

Comment: IIRC using the wrong type specifier is undefined bahviour in C.

Comment: I just tried Permutations with OPs first example. I noticed that when you have the declarations and printf in that particular order with arguments of course, the output (i.e. the values printed) are same. For all other cases, the printf with %f on int, prints 0 (tested on two different compilers). Though I totally agree that the result is undefined, but the same output does raises some eyebrows.

Comment: Just for the vocabulary, in C the word "cast" means an explicit conversion with the cast syntax as you do in your second example, `(float)`. So a cast is always written by yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably running this application on a 64-bit x86 architecture. On this architecture floating point arguments are passed in XMM registers, whereas integer arguments get passed in the general purpose registers. See [System V AMD64 ABI convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI_convention).

Because `%f` expects a floating point value:

```
printf("i is %f \n",i);
```

prints the value from XMM0 register, which happens to be the value of `k` assigned earlier and not `i` passed in RSI register. Assembly looks like this:

```
movl    $.LC1, %edi       # "k is %f \n"
movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0 # float k = 2
call    printf
movl    $1, %esi          # int i = 1
movl    $.LC2, %edi       # "i is %f \n"
call    printf            # prints xmm0 because of %f, not esi
```

If you reorder the assignments like this:

```
int i = 1;
printf("i is %f \n",i);

float k = 2;
printf("k is %f \n",k);
```

It prints:

```
i is 0.000000 
k is 2.000000
```

Because XMM0 register happens to have value of 0.

**[Update]**
It is reproducible on a 32-bit x86 as well. On this platform `printf()` is basically casting `int*` to `double*` and then reading that `double`. Let's modify the example to make it easy to see:

```
int main() {
    float k = 2;
    int i = -1;
    printf("k is %f \n",k);
    printf("i is %f \n",i,i);
}
```

64-bit output:

```
k is 2.000000 
i is 2.000000
```

32-bit output:

```
k is 2.000000 
i is -nan
```

That is, 2 `int`s with value of -1 look like a `double` 0xffffffffffffffff which is a `NaN` value.

Comment: Thanks, I thought just saying "it is undefined behaviour" would be too easy. )

Comment: I can reproduce this on 32 bit x86 architecture

Answer (score 8):

First, with any variadic function such as `printf()`, all integer values of a type shorter than `int` are passed as `int` (or `unsigned int` in some cases on some platforms), and all `float` values are passed as `double`.  Your `(float)a` therefore is cast a second time to `double`.

Secondly, `printf()` itself takes you at your word.  If you pass garbage in, you get garbage out.  More accurately, if you pass an integer where you tell `printf()` to expect a `double`, `printf()` will try to read a `double` from the parameter list.  What happens next is undefined behaviour.

Some compilers - notably GCC - will report type mismatches between literal string formats and the corresponding parameter list.  If your regular compiler does not do that analysis, consider using a compiler that will - at least for preliminary compilations to sort out the compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not do any type conversions based on format specifiers like `%f`.  Each parameter is passed in the normal manner, and giving an argument that does not match its format specifier is a bug in your program resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: printf() do typecasting see printf("i is %d \n",i);  this prints char nvalue into int

Comment: No, it doesn't.  That's normal type promotion in parameter passing where the receiving type is unknown and happens with every variadic function and with every function without a prototype.  Even a `%c` format specifier expects an `int` argument (which it then interprets as if it had been promoted from `char`).

Comment: @Mr.32, that's called integer promotion, which is distinct from typecasting.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("i is %d \n",i);
```

Nothing weird here. The character `a` is number 97 in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
printf("a is %f \n",a);
```

`a` is an int with the value 5. In memory, that'll be the bytes `[0x5 0x0 0x0 0x0]`. This command lies to printf, though. It says "just trust me that `a` points to a float". printf believes you. Floats are pretty weird, but basically they work like scientific notation but in base 2 instead of base 10. By random chance, the way that you specify 2.1688 as a float happens to be `[0x5 0x0 0x0 0x0]`. So that's what printf shows you.

```
printf("a is %f \n",(float)a);
```

Here you've told the compiler you want to convert `a` into a float before printf sees it. The C compiler knows how to change things to express 5 in the weird float format. So printf gets what it expects, and you see 5.0000

**Follow-up cool experiment:** Want to see something else neat? Try

```
union data {
    int i;
    float f;
    char ch[4];
};
union data d;
d.i = 5;
printf("How 5 is represented in memory as an integer:\n");
printf("0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X\n", v.ch[0], v.ch[1], v.ch[2], v.ch[3]);
d.f = 5.0;
printf("How 5 is represented in memory as a float:\n");
printf("0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X\n", v.ch[0], v.ch[1], v.ch[2], v.ch[3]);

// OUTPUT:
// How 5 is represented in memory as an integer:
// 0x5 0x0 0x0 0x0
// How 5 is represented in memory as a float:
// 0x0 0x0 0xFFFFFFA0 0x40
```

You can actually see how the C compiler changes the data around for you (assuming this works...)

Comment: What? Is `[0x5 0x0 0x0 0x0]` written in big or little endian?

Comment: Little endian, which means that the smallest address has the least-significant byte. Your mileage may vary though. Compile it on your machine and see what happens...

Comment: I think you missed the fact that `%f` isn't for `float` but for `double` arguments. In the case of va_arg functions all `float` are silently converted to `double` before being passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

It is even more interesting. I tested it on three different linux machines and got two different results for second output line:

```
gcc 4.5.1     32bit: a is -0.000000
gcc 4.5.1 -Ox 32bit: a is 0.000000
gcc 4.5.1     64bit: a is 0.000000
gcc 4.6.2     64bit: a is 0.000000
```